# Read File from server and upload that to Anonfile

Tags: python, python-requests, bytesio, bytestream

So i m trying to read a video from a server and then store that as bytes and then upload that file on Anonfile. But i dont want to save that file on local storage. I'm using BytesIO to read that file as binary and able to read. But when i try to upload it fails.

**UPDATE: Now it is working.**

```
r = requests.post(upload_url, files=file_info)
```

But how can i set file name while uploading

Comment: I am no Python expert but it might be useful to others to see what error you get when you say it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and it working fine. Even the read video using BytesIO has been uploaded to anonfiles.
please use **print(r.json())** to print the json response.
Please provide more details and specific error message if it is still not working for you.

Comment: Ya I checked that again i think i fixed that by my self... LOL.